# How to set redirect on details page using Angular and RxJs when get only one item in response array?

Tags: angular, routes, rxjs

I have this data:

```
  objects$ = new Observable<Object[]>();
    this.objects$ = this.serv$
      .getObjects()
      .pipe(map((res) => res.objects));
```

Template *objects.component*:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="objects$ | async as objects; else noObjects">
 <ng-container [ngSwitch]="objects?.length">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="1"> ...DETAILED INFO HERE... </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault> ...OBJECT CARDS... </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

How and were to add condition for redirect to `/object:id` when `objects.length === 1` instead of using `ngSwitch`?

Also route `/object:id` will be used as a link from object cards.

Comment: What do you mean by  "redirect to `/object:id`" ? You mean as soon as you receive the HTTP response, if ther eis only 1 object, you want the user to go to a differente page ?

Comment: @Random Yes I mean it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add it to your pipe after your map function.

Using `takeWhile` will emit items until it returns `false`, when `false` is returned it will unsubscribe. So, the example below we keep emitting values until length is 1.

```js
  objects$ = new Observable<Object[]>();
    this.objects$ = this.serv$
      .getObjects()
      .pipe(
        map((res) => res.objects),
        takeWhile(objs => {
          if(objs.length === 1) {
            this.router.navigate(['/object:id']);
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        })
      );
```